# python3 - why is size of string bigger than encode

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3, the size of a string such as `'test'.__sizeof__()` returns `73`. However, if I encode it as utf-8, `'test'.encode().__sizeof__()` returns `37`.

Why does the size of string significantly larger than the size of its encoding in utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPython, up to and including 3.2, unicode characters, which became str characters in 3.x, were stored as either 16 or 32 bit unsigned ints, depending on whether one had a 'narrow' or 'wide' build.  (Always narrow on Windows, both used on linux).  In 3.3 and following, CPython switched to a flexible string representation (FSR), using 1, 2, or 4 bytes (8, 16, or 32 bits) per char, depending on the width needed for the 'widest' char in the string.  See [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)

For 64 bit 3.4.3, `'test'.__sizeof__ == 53`, while still `b'test'.__sizeof__ == 37`.  Since both are using 1 byte per char, the extra 16 bytes are extra overhead in a string object.  Part of that is the hidden specification of whether the string is using 1, 2, or 4 bytes per char.  For comparison, `'tes\u1111'.__sizeof__() == 82` and `'tes\U00011111'.__sizeof__() == 92`.
(No, I do not know why the jump to 82.  One would probably have to check the code to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

`str` in python 3 is typically stored as 16-bit integers instead of bytes, unlike the encoded `bytes` object. This makes the string twice as large. Some extra metadata is probably also present, inflating the object further.

Comment: would you know where can I find documentation about this?

Comment: @uday `bytes` are pretty simple, a sequence of bytes. You may find some interesting info about `str` in https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/unicode.html